# With doxygen, when should the comments be placed before the entity, and when after?

Tags: c++, comments, doxygen, cross-language

Here are two styles of commenting on an entity (e.g. in a C/C++ like language).

Style 1:

```
// This is a comment
// about foo
int foo;

// This is a comment
// about bar
int bar;
```

Style 2:

```
int foo;
    // This is a comment
    // about foo

int bar;
    // This is a comment
    // about bar
```

I know that, usually, when writing a doxygen comment, it's typically appears before the documented entity, e.g.:

```
/// This is a doxygen comment
/// about foo
int foo;

/// This is a doxygen comment
/// about bar
int bar;
```

Is that always the case, or can I place it after the entity, as in the second commenting-style above?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can place your doxygen comments after the commented-on item, but in that case you have to add a special  marking to the comment. This is explained in the [Doxygen documentation](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html):

> #### Putting documentation after members
>
> If you want to document the members of a file, struct, union, class,
> or enum, it is sometimes desired to place the documentation block
> after the member instead of before. For this purpose you have to put
> an additional `<` marker in the comment block. Note that this also works
> for the parameters of a function.
>
> Here are some examples:
>
> ```
> int var; /*!< Detailed description after the member */
> ```
>
> This block can be used to put a Qt style detailed documentation block
> after a member. Other ways to do the same are:
> ...
>
> ```
> int var; ///< Detailed description after the member
>          ///<
> ```